# Class is not inheriting DB correctly

Tags: php, oop, pdo

So I have a DB class that looks like this

```
class db{

    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'root';
    private $con;

    public function db(){
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=myDB", $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
        $this->con = $dbh;
        echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
```

And my index.php

```
include('db.class.php');
include('todo.class.php');
include('dressTemplate.inc.php');

$db = new db;

$todo = new todo($db);
```

And my todo.class.php start like this

```
class todo{

function todo(db $db){
    $this->db = $db;
} 

public function render($post) {

    $db &= $this->db;
```

But then I get this notice

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in todo.class.php on line 11

Notice: Object of class db could not be converted to int in todo.class.php on line 11
```

How do I get db to be defined correctly in todo.class.php?

Comment: Why don't you use a `__construct()`

Comment: I'm just used to using the class name as constructor, but it seems that __construct is best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class todo {

  var $db;

  __construct(&$db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function render($post) {
    $db = &$this->db;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `&=`. That is equal to `$db = $db & $this->db`. And first notice is there because PHP knows nothing of `$db` (it's undeclared yet). Second notice is because you're trying to do `(null) & (object)`. First will be converted to `int` first and then 'object could not be converted' will appear, obviously (since PHP will try to treat whole expression as `int`)

That's it: your object variable is set correctly, but your `$db` variable is local and has nothing to do with it. And you're doing something strange with object via `&` ([bitwise AND](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php))

*Tip*: do not use old PHP4 way to define class constructors - unless you're using PHP4. In PHP5 there's [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) magic method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your todo class should either use the `__construct` or a public function with the class name, e.g.

```
class todo {

    var $db;

    __construct (db $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // OR

    public function todo(db $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    } 

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a public constructor: `__construct()`
This works fine for me:

```
class db{

    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'root';
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=myDB", $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
        $this->con = $dbh;
        echo 'Connected to database<br />';
    }
}



class todo{

    public function __construct(db $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```